# how to push code to remote git repository without pulling and overwriting the existing code

Tags: git, gitlab, push, pull

I have this situation where I am migrating the huge size of code from SVN to GIT like 115GB individual repos. the problem is while migrating, the code was expanding like anything. 3GB code was expanding to 60GB. So I am planning to do by folder by folder migration. Now is there a way that I can push my code to Gitlab without pulling the existing remote data and the previous code in the repo should not be overwritten.

When i use this command:
`git push --set-upstream origin master -f`

Its overwriting the existing code. I want to add the new folders in the existing git repo without pulling the code(Since i have less disk space).

Can anyone has a solution for this to push the code to remote repository without pulling the existing code and should not overwrite the existing code in gitlab? like merge the new code without pulling or overwriting in the remote repository.

Comment: Are you creating a git repo for each svn folder or you are just trying to add folders one by one to the same git repo?

Comment: Here you mentioned without pulling the code, it means your code is already in Gitlab or you mean, pulling the SVN code?

Comment: try this syntax. `git push origin --set-upstream <branch_name>`  your force pushing it.

Comment: Hi @Francesco i am trying to add new folders in the existing git folder. as i dont have enough disk space i am migrating folder by folder from svn, then i want to push them into one git repository. but with the force push it is overwriting the existing folders. Is there a way. is it possible to do update a git repository without pulling and overwriting.?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer there is already code in my git repository. I want push new folders into that git repo without pulling the existing data. when i use force push its overwriting the existing data. how can i do this?